# Bulk remove query strings from URLs In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, url, query-string

I'm writing a code in Javascript where I wanted to replace all the query strings in a string of comma separated urls. But I'm able to do it only till some extent. Below is my code.

```js
const urls = '//i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-2.psd?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1&hei=77&wid=92&qlt=100,1&resMode=sharp2&size=92,77&chrss=full,//i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-4.psd?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1&hei=59&wid=92&qlt=100,1&resMode=sharp2&size=92,59&chrss=full,//i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-6.psd?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1&hei=79&wid=92&qlt=100,1&resMode=sharp2&size=92,79&chrss=full,//i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-7.psd?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1&hei=79&wid=92&qlt=100,1&resMode=sharp2&size=92,79&chrss=full,//i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-8.psd?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1&hei=59&wid=92&qlt=100,1&resMode=sharp2&size=92,59&chrss=full,//i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-9.psd?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1&hei=47&wid=92&qlt=100,1&resMode=sharp2&size=92,47&chrss=full,https://i.dell.com/das/dih.ashx/57x57/sites/csimages/Video_Imagery/all/lati-ys-video-thumbnail-hero-1280x720.jpg';

const urlsWithoutQueryParams = urls.replace(/(\?.*?(?=,)|\?.+$)/g, '');

console.log(urlsWithoutQueryParams);
```

And my Expected output is

> //i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-2.psd
> //i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-4.psd
> //i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-6.psd
> //i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-7.psd
> //i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-8.psd
> //i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-9.psd
> https://i.dell.com/das/dih.ashx/57x57/sites/csimages/Video_Imagery/all/lati-ys-video-thumbnail-hero-1280x720.jpg

Please lemme know where I'm going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Your pattern matches only part of your query strings, https://regex101.com/r/ajEJbZ/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps you!

### Regular way

If you needed more elaboration just comment!

```js
const urls = '//i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-2.psd?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1&hei=77&wid=92&qlt=100,1&resMode=sharp2&size=92,77&chrss=full,//i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-4.psd?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1&hei=59&wid=92&qlt=100,1&resMode=sharp2&size=92,59&chrss=full,//i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-6.psd?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1&hei=79&wid=92&qlt=100,1&resMode=sharp2&size=92,79&chrss=full,//i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-7.psd?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1&hei=79&wid=92&qlt=100,1&resMode=sharp2&size=92,79&chrss=full,//i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-8.psd?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1&hei=59&wid=92&qlt=100,1&resMode=sharp2&size=92,59&chrss=full,//i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-9.psd?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1&hei=47&wid=92&qlt=100,1&resMode=sharp2&size=92,47&chrss=full,https://i.dell.com/das/dih.ashx/57x57/sites/csimages/Video_Imagery/all/lati-ys-video-thumbnail-hero-1280x720.jpg';

const urlsWithoutQueryParams = urls
  .split(/,(?=\/\/|https:\/\/)/)
  .map((x) => x.replace(/\?.+$/, ''))
  .join(' ');

console.log(urlsWithoutQueryParams);
```

### Just regex solution:

This solution uses just one line of code.

```js
const urls = '//i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-2.psd?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1&hei=77&wid=92&qlt=100,1&resMode=sharp2&size=92,77&chrss=full,//i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-4.psd?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1&hei=59&wid=92&qlt=100,1&resMode=sharp2&size=92,59&chrss=full,//i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-6.psd?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1&hei=79&wid=92&qlt=100,1&resMode=sharp2&size=92,79&chrss=full,//i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-7.psd?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1&hei=79&wid=92&qlt=100,1&resMode=sharp2&size=92,79&chrss=full,//i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-8.psd?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1&hei=59&wid=92&qlt=100,1&resMode=sharp2&size=92,59&chrss=full,//i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-9.psd?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1&hei=47&wid=92&qlt=100,1&resMode=sharp2&size=92,47&chrss=full,https://i.dell.com/das/dih.ashx/57x57/sites/csimages/Video_Imagery/all/lati-ys-video-thumbnail-hero-1280x720.jpg';

const urlsWithoutQueryParams = urls.replace(/\?[^\/]+,\s*(?=\/\/|https:\/\/|$)/g, ' ');

console.log(urlsWithoutQueryParams);
```

Answer (score 1):

As all the URLs also contains `,`, there's no quick way to solve this using Regex (There's probably a solution in Regex, but sometimes Regex is not the only solution). Here's an alternate solution for your particular case:

```js
const urls =
  '//i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-2.psd?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1&hei=77&wid=92&qlt=100,1&resMode=sharp2&size=92,77&chrss=full,//i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-4.psd?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1&hei=59&wid=92&qlt=100,1&resMode=sharp2&size=92,59&chrss=full,//i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-6.psd?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1&hei=79&wid=92&qlt=100,1&resMode=sharp2&size=92,79&chrss=full,//i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-7.psd?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1&hei=79&wid=92&qlt=100,1&resMode=sharp2&size=92,79&chrss=full,//i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-8.psd?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1&hei=59&wid=92&qlt=100,1&resMode=sharp2&size=92,59&chrss=full,//i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-9.psd?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1&hei=47&wid=92&qlt=100,1&resMode=sharp2&size=92,47&chrss=full,https://i.dell.com/das/dih.ashx/57x57/sites/csimages/Video_Imagery/all/lati-ys-video-thumbnail-hero-1280x720.jpg';

const urlsWithoutQueryParams = urls
  .split(/(?:,?\/\/|https:\/\/)/)
  .filter(Boolean)
  .map((x) => x.split('?')[0])
  .join(',');

console.log(urlsWithoutQueryParams);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of the commas in the query params, it might be easier to just match the URL path parts and join them back together into a string:

```js
const urls = '//i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-2.psd?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1&hei=77&wid=92&qlt=100,1&resMode=sharp2&size=92,77&chrss=full,//i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-4.psd?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1&hei=59&wid=92&qlt=100,1&resMode=sharp2&size=92,59&chrss=full,//i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-6.psd?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1&hei=79&wid=92&qlt=100,1&resMode=sharp2&size=92,79&chrss=full,//i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-7.psd?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1&hei=79&wid=92&qlt=100,1&resMode=sharp2&size=92,79&chrss=full,//i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-8.psd?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1&hei=59&wid=92&qlt=100,1&resMode=sharp2&size=92,59&chrss=full,//i.dell.com/is/image/DellContent/content/dam/ss2/products/laptops-and-2-in-1s/latitude/13-9330-touch/media-gallery/2in1/notebook-latitude-13-9330-gray-gallery-9.psd?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1&hei=47&wid=92&qlt=100,1&resMode=sharp2&size=92,47&chrss=full,https://i.dell.com/das/dih.ashx/57x57/sites/csimages/Video_Imagery/all/lati-ys-video-thumbnail-hero-1280x720.jpg';

const urlsWithoutQueryParams = urls.match(/(?:https:)?\/\/[^?]*/g).join(',')

console.log(urlsWithoutQueryParams)
```